# How to display touch points on screen

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-note, 4.3-jelly-bean

My Galaxy Note with stock ROM had an option via `Settings > Developer > Show touch points` (or something like that). Now, I updated to CyanogenMod, based on Android 4.3 but I can't find an option similar to that anywhere.

My screen was damaged once. Since then, I needed to see the detected touch points on screen at all times, so I can see when the touchscreen gets stuck.

Is there an option (or even an app) for that? I Googled around and looked at the Play Store, but only found multi-touch tester apps. I need something that shows the touch points at all times and in all apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking a bit further I discovered that I have to click 7 times on Build number on phone details to enable the Developer settings.

Comment: I will, but I can only do it tomorrow (2 days after the question).