# How to show screen touches on Android 2.3

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, touchscreen

I have to show my Android 2.3 phone on a projector and I like audience to see what control I touch. There is a developer setting in Android 4 to show touches. 
How can I do it in Android 2.3? Is there an app for it?

Comment: It depends on your device. What phone are you using? Have you tried going to Settings > Device and clicking "Build Number" several times? That should enable developer settings. I had it on my old HTC desire on 2.3... without that build number thing but I know from my S4 that samsung hide it intitially.

Comment: Related: [How to display touch points on screen](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/51448)

Comment: It is a Sony Xperia X8. I tried to push the Build number sign several times but nothing showed up. Any idea?

Comment: @Nestor I'm not too familiar with Sony I'm afriad,  usually that works. Can you not see it through SETTINGS > Applications > Development?? If you have gone through all the options, try the XPeria X8 section on XDA developers, they will have an answer for sure. Sorry can't be of more help.

Comment: I couldn't find any setting for it. I try XDA, thanks for the tip.

Comment: At XDA, they don't consider the X8 as a "living" phone, it is deprecated, so nobody cares about my question :S